# How can I change my for loop full of if statements into more elegant/efficient code?

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8, java-stream

This is my string:

```
String field = "first=true, second=true"
```

My method operates on this string and recognises if it contains the `first=` and `second=` substrings, and if yes - based on the true/false following it calls other methods. The first and second substrings may be optional though. This is what I have so far:

```
void method(String field) {

      String[] splittedField = field.split(", ");
      for (String substring : splittedField) {
          if (substring.contains("first") {
              if (substring.contains("true") {
                  otherMethod("first", "true");
              } else if (substring.contains("false") {
                  otherMethod("first", "false");
              }
          } else if (substring.contains("second") {
              if (substring.contains("true") {
                  otherMethod("second", "true");
              } else if (substring.contains("false") {
                  otherMethod("second", "false");
              }
          }
      }

}
```

But perhaps there is a better/more efficient(and elegant?) way of solving that case?

Comment: Is the value of first(and second) always true/false and nothing else?

Comment: @TryinHard yes, however first or second might not be present in the string, there's a case where the string might be empty, or contain only `first=true` or only `second=false` etc :)

Comment: And I assume it should execute the `otherMethod` only once, right? I mean, if you have both `first` and `second` keys, it's shouldn't call `otherMethod` twice.

Comment: I need to call it twice, once for `first` and once for `second`, of course if both are present in the String

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
if (substring.contains("first") {
    if (substring.contains("true") {
        otherMethod("first", "true");
    } else if (substring.contains("false") {
        otherMethod("first", "false");
    }
 }
```

Above `if` can be coded as:

```
if (substring.contains("first") {
    String[] valueString = substring.split("=");            
    otherMethod("first", valueString[1]);
 }
```

Comment: OP, could the input String be as `first=, second=true`? With no value for a specific key.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it simply as follows:

```
String[] splittedField = field.split(", ");
for (String substring : splittedField) {
    String[] parts = substring.split("=");
    otherMethod(parts[0], parts[1]);
}
```

Comment: But this always calls the method. In the question, OP is checking that the method is called only for key/values `first=true/false, second=true/false`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need all the `if` statements.

For the checks, you could create a couple of sets, and for invoking the method, you could split each substring again, by `=`:

```
void method(String field) {

    Set<String> firstSecond = Set.of("first", "second");
    Set<String> trueFalse = Set.of("true", "false");

    String[] splittedField = field.split(", ");
    for (String substring : splittedField) {
        String[] args = substring.split("=");
        if (firstSecond.contains(args[0]) && trueFalse.contains(args[1])) {
            otherMethod(args[0], args[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: if you aren't using Java9+ yet, you could rewrite `Set.of` as follows:

```
Set<String> firstSecond = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("first", "second"));
```

Comment: Not very sure if OP should call the `otherMethod` only once, or it's allowed to be called multiple times? That's why an `else` between `contains("first")` and `contains("second")`

Comment: @AlexSomai I've refactored the code. OP invokes the method within a `for` loop and I'm doing the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this will eliminate the complex `if` structure.

```
public class Main {
    public static void method(String field) {
        int i = 0;
        // Make the flags false by default, 
        // in case you don't supply either or both of them in field.
        String[] flags = {"false", "false"};
        String[] splittedField = field.split(", ");
        for (String substring : splittedField) {
            String[] args = substring.split("=");
            flags[i] = args[1];
            ++i;
        }
        othermethod(flags[0], flags[1]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String field = "first=true, second=false";
            method(field);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a solution that uses `Stream`s, you can perform something like:

```
void invokeOtherMethod(String field) {
    Map<String, Boolean> mapFromString = Arrays.stream(field.split(","))
            .map(s -> s.trim().split("="))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> Boolean.valueOf(a[1])));
    for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : mapFromString.entrySet()) {
        otherMethod(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

*Note*: The change in the signature of `otherMethod` on purpose to use:

```
void otherMethod(String key, boolean value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP's question and his comment, this is enough I think?:

```
void method(String field) {

      Arrays.stream(field.split(", "))
            .forEach(v -> {
                 String[] args = v.split("=");
                 otherMethod(args[0], args[1]);
            })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an improved version for your code. Some of the point that you should keep in mind.
1. You can directly call the contains method in the otherMethod as it is also expecting boolean.

```
void method(String field) {
  String[] splittedField = field.split(", ");
  for (String substring : splittedField) {
    if (substring.contains("first") {
        otherMethod("first", substring.contains("true"));
    } else if (substring.contains("second") {
        otherMethod("second", substring.contains("true"));
    }
  }
}
```